# How to send value with onclick event?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, events, imagebutton

I have the following button

```
   <asp:ImageButton ID="button1" runat="server" 
   ImageUrl="~/image.jpg"
   CommandName = "id"
   CommandArgument = "1"
   onclick="button1_Click"
   />
```

and in code behind

```
protected void button1_Click(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)
{
    Response.Write(e.commandName);
}
```

this does not work!!, So my question is how to get value frombutton control?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For this to work you need to subscribe to the [Command event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.button.command.aspx) instead of the Click event.  This is used when following the [command pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command_pattern) in ASP.NET